# How to get the JSON in joomla 3

Tags: php, json, joomla

I want to know as Joomla 3 supports JSON format, how to get the output in json format as in we easily get the data in XML format.  If  possible pls reply on it. I'll very thankful to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

// Set the MIME type for JSON output.
$document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');

// Output the JSON data.
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you review the code in the /installation folder, it uses AJAX requests (and inherently, JSON strings) to function.  This should help you out some.